# PostgreSQL - Update inner json

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column `jdata` of type `jsonb` inside a table 'JTABLE'. A sample `jdata` looks like this :

```
{
 "id" : 12,
 "address" : {
     "houseName": {
        "name" : "Jackson",
         "lang" : "ENG"
     } 
  } 
}
```

How can i query to update the `lang` to `anotherValue` for this?

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work :

`UPDATE JTABLE SET jdata -> 'address'->'houseName'-> 'lang' = '"DEU"' where jdata->>'id' = '12';`

This doesn't work! Any help?

EDIT:

This overwrites my value and i  get this when i run :

```
{
 "id" : 12,
 "address" : {
     "houseName": {
         "lang" : "DEU"
     } 
  } 
}
```

I lost key `name`.

I'm trying this query now :

`SELECT jsonb_set(jdata, 'address,houseName}', '{"lang":"DEU"}'::jsonb) FROM JTABLE where jdata->>'id' = '12';`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a useless phrase on SO; please only ever give an exact and detailed description of what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. Imagine you work helpdesk and one of your users phones up saying only "my computer doesn't work" - what's wrong with it?

Comment: `jsonb_set` function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry, I'm a newb and i really need help in doing this patch update. It also throws me a cast exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is wrong, the 2nd statement should be a path to the `json key` you wish to update.

The query to view your update should look like :

```
SELECT jsonb_set(jdata, '{address,houseName,lang}', '"DEU"') FROM JTABLE where jdata->'id' = '12';
```

The final query to update :

```
UPDATE JTABLE SET jdata = jsonb_set(jdata, '{address,houseName,lang}', '"DEU"') WHERE jdata->'id' = '12';
```

Also don't type cast a `record` to `jsonb.

Comment: Yea! I figured this out later! Thank you